# how to read all folder names in directory and write folder names as header in CSV python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working with images to extract data into CSV. but currently, I want to name the header of CSV as an image folder name. The structure is this

[image]

The structure for my CSV file looks like this

[image: as]

My code is

```
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO_T_ID/yolov5/runs/detect/exp5/crops/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)

for f in files:
 dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(files)) 
 print(f)
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: It's possible but you need to establish some business rules, what if there are nested folders which name should be used? please provide an example output see [mcve]

Comment: What does your code do? What does it not do that it should? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking a specific question with a good problem description is half the way to getting a good answer!

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I am fresh on StackOverflow so that's, why I didn't, follow the protocol but I remembered for next. I solved my problem by the below Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply using [**`os.listdir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) ?

```
import os
import csv

crops_dir = r"C:\Users\abokey\Desktop\crops"
img_folder_names = os.listdir(crops_dir)

with open(crops_dir+r'\output_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(img_folder_names)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved my problem with your code. Have a nice day SIR

Comment: @UmarAziz you can say thanks by accepting the answer :)

Comment: @Ramesh I can't upvote this answer due to new user